# Is there a good way to validate jQuery code?

Tags: jquery

I am a bonifide jQuery novice and I have some jquery code that I have pieced together, but I keep getting an error when the page loads. Problem is I am not sure if I have all the curly brackets and parenthesis closed properly and would really appreciate another set of eyes on this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slideshow').cycle({
        fx:  'scrollLeft', 
        timeout: 8000
    });
});
    $('#freeQuote form')
       .validate({
         submitHandler: function(form) {
           $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                success: function() {
                var Image = $('<img />').attr({src:'_images/free-quote-confirm.png', width:231, height:267, alt:"Success"});
                    $('#freeQuote form').hide();
                    $('#freeQuote').append(Image)
                }
           });
         }
       }); 

  $('#news-signup form')
    .validate({
     submitHandler: function(form) {
       $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            success: function() {
            var Image = $('<img />').attr({src:'_images/register-thanks.png', width:332, height:35, alt:"Success"});
                $('#news-signup form').hide();
                $('#news-signup').append(Image)
            }
       });
     }
  });
```

I have this loading from its own .js file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, load the page in Chrome and press Ctrl-Shift-J to bring up the JavaScript console. This will instantly highlight any syntax errors.

Alternatively, get [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox.

As for your code, I think you should start smaller if you don't know what you're doing. Get the `cycle()` function working first, then try one of the validations, then the other. Make one bit work at a time, and every time you add something new, try it out to see if it works, or doesn't, and if it generates errors.

Once you get to that stage, follow [Robert's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842762/is-there-a-good-way-to-validate-jquery-code/3842784#3842784) advice and run it through JSLint. That'll show you where you're doing things wrong, like missing semicolons on the ends of statements.

Comment: Or get [FirebugLite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) which will work on IE6+, Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome

Comment: Good advice. I got it worked out. Thanks for the process advice.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, http://www.jslint.com/

Your code returned the following errors:

> Error:
>
> Problem at line 14 character 50:
>   Missing semicolon.
>
> $('#freeQuote').append(Image)
>
> Problem at line 27 character 48:
>   Missing semicolon.
>
> $('#news-signup').append(Image)
>
> Implied global: $
>   1,2,7,10,12,13,14,20,23,25,26,27,
>   document 1

JSLint hates everything I do :P

Comment: I think JSLint will throw up too many errors for a newbie. That's not to say it's not an extremely useful tool, but if you don't know what you're looking for there's a lot of relative 'noise'.

Comment: @Skilldrick I agree it can be a little overwhelming but there's no better way to learn from your mistakes.

Comment: It is one thing to learn from your mistakes, not knowing the right way is another issue altogether. JSLint shows me my problems but does not teach me how to correct them!

Comment: @fmz, absolutely, that's what the jQuery Tutorials (http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) are good for.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to help validate simple things like nesting of parens or curly braces is by using an editor like Notepad++ or Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Use any powerful editor for JS.
Aptana, PHPStorm are the ones I've tried and saw that, at least PHPStorm, show very good notices when something's wrong in your JS code (including jQuery)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.jslint.com/

you're missing a semicolon in two places: $('#freeQuote').append(Image) and $('#news-signup').append(Image)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of good ideas already posted ... only one thing to add. **Use QUnit or a similar Javascript unit testing tool** to run unit tests that actually exercise your code. There's no better way to know it's "right" than to define what "right" means, and then run it and verify that it's "right".

QUnit is what the JQuery authors use to ensure JQuery works right. [Here's a getting started link](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/chad_myers/archive/2008/08/28/getting-started-with-jquery-qunit-for-client-side-javascript-testing.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

even for jQuery and without using browser specific plugins i prefer [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The following lines should *enclose* everything else:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //  ...
    //  everything else
    //  ...
});
```

Also, the short  (and recommended) form of that is:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    //  ...
    //  everything else
    //  ...
});
```